# Can't change CSS color attribute in a disabled text input field

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

Simple question (I hope):

In IE 11 (11.0.11), I am trying to use CSS to get the text color of a disabled html input field to be not grayed out (ie black).

When I click through this reference, I see:[image]

But when I do "show source", then copy all source into a new (local) file, and open that, the input box text is still gray.

[image]

So my question is: Is this an aspect of loading/displaying it off of my local machine vs. from the internet, or something that I've missed in creating the local file or some other configuration that can resolve this issue?

-Edit-

Here is the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Disabled Text Boxes</title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
    fieldset {border:0;margin-bottom:12px;}
    label {font:normal 13px/19px verdana;display:block;}
    input {border:1px solid #000;}
    input[disabled='disabled'] {
        background:yellow;
        color:blue;
        cursor:default;
    }
    input.disabled {
        background:yellow;
        color:blue;
        cursor:default;
           font-size:24px;
    }
    </style>
    
    
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <fieldset>
    <label for="username">Enabled:</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        id="username" />
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
    <label for="dis">Disabled text box using input[disabled='disabled']:</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        id="dis"
        disabled="disabled"
        value="you cant edit this" />
    </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
    <label for="dis">Disabled text box using class="disabled" in CSS:</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        id="dis"
        disabled="disabled"
        class="disabled"
        value="you cant edit this" />
    </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Adding `font-size:24px;` to input[disabled='disabled'] didn't change the styling. When I added `font-size:24px;` to input:disabled, the resulting rendering looks like
[image]

Thanks

Comment: It works fine on my machine. This is probabaly not the case, but could you have missed this maybe? input[disabled='disabled'] {
 background:yellow;
 color:blue;
 cursor:default;
}

Comment: @Valius79 No, didn't miss it. I know because I tried setting font-size:...px and that worked. It's just `color` that won't work. Can you confirm that you are using IE 11?

Comment: Post the actual code that you have on your local machine

Comment: Perhaps Quirks Mode? Try and call the page via HTTP, not via the local file system. (And make sure it has a doctype that doesn’t trigger quirks, and the rest of the HTML is valid as well.)

Comment: Yes, I was using ie11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment,This was a quirks issue